# Best way to arrange different views in a single page website

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, single-page-application

I have an app using AngularJS and Bootstrap. 
The way I have arranged my different views is using `ng-show`. That is, views change according to button presses, etc. and enabling/disabling `ng-show` values.

I have a single HTML file with a lot of DIVs. All these DIVs show/dissapear.

My questions are:

- Is this the usual way of doing a single page web app? I.e. have all the views in different DIV's and show/hide them as needed?
- Is there a more efficient way to arrange all different views in to a more structured way than having all of them in a single HTML file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If your application is quite big and you have more than two or three views, you have to use a router like ngRouter, UI Router is more powerful but more complex. This is the best solution.

If your application is rather small (two or three views), and doesn't evolve, you can use [ng-switch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch).

Ng-if may be an option but it is less convenient.

But you should avoid ng-show, because DOM elements are always in the page and just hide.

Answer (score 1):

You should really use a routing service, such as ngRouter or ui.router, because if the app becomes more complex it will become increasingly hard to maintain.

[Here's](https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating) one article I googled on routing and using templates in Angular.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to show multiple pages on the single page applications on according to their menu's using `Routing` in angularjs.

AngularJS Single Page Template and ng.Net Template, Both are based on mvc pattern, and easy to understand. So in below have some references. Check it.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5af151b2-9ed2-4809-bfe8-27566bfe7d83

https://github.com/BBird40/ng.NET

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/48d928e3-9b5c-4faf-b46f-d6baa7d9886c